# I need to make a mutable list starting with two false values and continuing with true values up to N, can I use a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I need a function (lets call it list(n)) that creates a list containing two false values followed by n-1 true values, is it possible to use a list comprehension with two statements inside? I need to be able to manipulate the list with lines like list(n)[5] = true which isn't really working unless I assign the function to a variable like list(n) = list.

Below is my function, I have tried changing the fourth value to false and then calling list_true(5) which didn't return what I expected. Only after assigning the function output to the variable list did it do what I wanted (fourth item needs to change from true to false).

```
def list_true(n):

    return [False for i in range(2)] + [True for i in range(n-1)]

list_true(5)[3] = False

list_true(5)

list_true(5) = list

list[3] = False
```

Comment: is the length of the list variable?

Comment: It sounds like you expect `list_true(5)[3] = False` to change the value you will get next time you can `list_true(5)`. Is the what you're after?

Comment: Every time you call the function, a new list gets created.  The whole point of having variables is the ability to save information in them for later use, which can include their manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only after assigning the function output to the variable list did it do what I wanted (fourth item needs to change from true to false).

Right. This is how Python works. Whether your return value is a list comprehension, a list expression made by concatenating two lists, or a new list generated with loops, each function call generates a new list. Call the function once, assign it to a variable, and as you discovered, things will work.

> is it possible to use a list comprehension with two statements inside?

depends on what you mean by "two statements". In general you can write things like

```
[x + y for x in range(3) for y in range(5)]
```

but having two `for` conditions in the comprehension is essentially two *nested* loops, and I think in your case you are not asking for nesting. You simply are looking for two Falses and multiple Trues that *follow* the Falses. Your expression, with two *separate* comprehensions, was fine.

Aside: Another way to make a mutable list with two `False`s and the rest `True`, you can, interesting enough, avoid comprehensions, with the following expression:

```
[False, False, *([True] * (n-1))]
```

It's a little idiomatic but it looks like a single list from the outside which you might find nice.

Comment: Wow, someone likes to downvote.  But anyhow, as a oneliner, I like the last one.  Although my answer is a bit faster. However, why `-1` and not `-2`?

Comment: The OP stated in the question "that creates a list containing two false values followed by n-1 true values" so I was taking the questioner literally there. They probably did want a total of n values in the list, so focusing on that part of the question would indeed mean that I should have used n-2. Sieve of Erastothenes and all that :) And yes your answer is much likely faster...I was shooting for a single one-shot expression without a comprehension. Ken Bloom's answer has a cute comprehension. Was just having some fun. :)

Comment: And yes, if it isn't fun, we should be here.  Cheers.

Comment: I need to be able to edit the list like this: list(5)[3] = False and then calling the function list(5) would output the newly edited list. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: You certainly _can_ say `list(5)[3] = False`. It will call your function, return a list, and then update the fourth element. But once that assignment is past, you generally cannot access that list again, *unless you trick the function into returning the SAME list* as in a previous call. My opinion on this is that it will needlessly confuse users, because the expectation for a call like `list(5)` is for it to construct a new list. Aside: you shouldn't use the name `list` for your personal function because most Python programmers will expect that word to refer to the type list. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with your list comprehensions. Your list comprehensions work fine. Your problem is that you've misunderstood how functions work.

Calling your function creates a list. Calling it twice creates *two* lists. Modifying the first list won't do anything to the second. You can't just keep calling `list_true(5)` over and over and expect changes to persist from one list to a completely different list.

You need to create *one* list and keep it, by assigning the function output to a variable and using the variable. Judging by your question, you seem to have realized that would work (although you got it backward when posting). Use a variable.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not recommended: one does not expect the return value of `list_true` to be a reference.

However, it's possible:

```
>>> def list_true(n, list_by_n={}):
...    return list_by_n.setdefault(n, [False, False] + [True]*(n-1))
...
>>> list_true(5)
[False, False, True, True, True, True]
>>> list_true(5)[3] = False
>>> list_true(5)
[False, False, True, False, True, True]
```

Here's how it works. First, `list_true` has a argument with a default value. This default value is used only once, when the function is first called, and then stored in the function state. Then, with `setdefault`, we look for the value mapped to the key `n` and return it if it exists. Otherwise, the value mapped to `n` is set to `[False, False] + [True]*(n-1)` (the initial value) and returned. To summarize: `list_true` will create the list if it doesn't exist, and then return always the same reference.

But this is a trick. You could get the same result but a clearer design with a class:

```
>>> class ListStore:
...    def __init__(self):
...        self._list_by_n = {}
...
...    def get(self, n):
...        return self._list_by_n.setdefault(n, [False, False] + [True]*(n-1))
```

The suffix `Store` (you may find a better one) is meant to give the indication that instances of the class will return references.

```
>>> list_store = ListStore()
>>> list_store.get(5)
[False, False, True, True, True, True]
>>> list_store.get(5)[3] = False
>>> list_store.get(5)
[False, False, True, False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `*` operator like:

#### Code:

```
N = 6
x = [True] * N
x[:2] = [False] * 2
print(x)
```

#### Results:

```
[False, False, True, True, True, True]
```

Comment: I tried this as well but the result I am looking for is a way to use the list and change it by only using the function. So for example I need to be able to edit the list like this:     
list(5)[3] = False and then calling the function list(5) would output the new edited list.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
[x>1 for x in range(n-1)]
```

Comment: This should do what?